# Exponential Distribution with Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$$f(y) = \begin{cases} \int_0^y\frac1\beta e^{\frac {-t}\beta}dt = -e^{\frac {-y}\beta}+1 & \text{for } 0 ≤ y < ∞,\\ 0& \text{for } elsewhere\end{cases}$$

$P(Y>3) = 1 - P(Y ≤ 3) = 1 - (-e^{-3/\beta}+1) = .1353 $

When I take log to both sides, I get 3.453.
When I take ln to both sides, I get 1.4998. When I plug it back into the equation, 1.4998 looks right...However, I puzzle why there is a difference?

Before this, could anyone please make sure $\beta = 1.4998$?

(1) P(Y<0) = 0, right?

(2) P(Y<1) = $-e^{1/1.4998} + 1 = .4866 $, right?

Comment: The $\beta=1.4998$ is, to the level of accuracy given, correct. As to your $\log$ issue, the logarithm to the base $10$ of $e^x$ is $x\log e$, not $x$.

Comment: so Ln should be the right one? Also, could you please check (1) and (2)?

Comment: You **can** use $\log$, but you will need $\log e$, so it is more work. The natural and easy thing is $\ln$. The answer to (1) is correct. As to (2), I expect you can handle a calculator better than I can.

Comment: @user111548: $1-e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}}$ is $F(y)$, not $f(y)$

Comment: @Alex: so the whole thing is wrong?

Comment: @Alex: I still think this is right though? I do not see what I need to change based on your comment. Please let me know what I need to change if any, thx

Comment: @user111548: I'm sorry, is the $P(Y >3) = 0.1353$ an additional condition?

Comment: The information I am given is P(Y<3) = .1353

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your confusion was probably the probability density function:
$$
f(y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
\frac{1}{\beta}e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}} & y >0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

If you integrate it, you get cumulative distribution function $F(y)=\int_{0}^{y}f(t)dt=1-e^{-\frac{y}{\beta}}$, hence what you wrote as the definition of your pdf is incorrect. Now you have the additional information which you can use to find $\beta$, which happens to be equal to $\beta = -\frac{3}{\log 0.1353}$.

Now you can use this information to find $F(1)=1-e^{-\frac{1}{\beta}}$